# Check if two variables are in the Database Kotlin

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am currently working on a website with kotlin xhtml and sql.
I just made a Register Website which writes all the values from the User(Name,username,password etc.) in a database.
Now i want to code a login page.I made two forms (username and password).
Now i want to check if these values exist in my Database and if they are from the Same User.
[This is my Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEpM.png)

This is my Code:

```
fun logincheckdata(ctx: Context){
    ctx.html(
        Page {
            val loginusernameValue = ctx.formParam(loginusernamefield)
            val loginpasswordValue = ctx.formParam(loginpasswordfield)
            if (
                loginpasswordValue == null
                || usernamefield == null
            ){
                Head {
                    title{
                        +"Login Failed"
                    }
                }
                Body{
                    div {
                        +"Please fill out all gaps!"
                    }
                    div {
                        form {
                            action = "./"
                            label {
                                button {
                                    type = ButtonType.submit
                                    + "Back to Login"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }else{
            }



        }
    )


}
```

And I want to Check if the variables loginusernameValue and loginpasswordValue are in my Database.

I hope you can help me to solve my problem :D

Comment: Never ever store passwords in plain text! To you question: Where exactly is the problem? `SELECT * FROM db WHERE username = ?`

Comment: But unfortunately this line doesnt work with Kotlin: "Classifier 'SELECT' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here"  + "Unresolved reference: FROM and WHERE ". I think its the right way but how can i implement it?

Comment: put up your code in the question and then maybe somebody might be able to point out the mistake.

Comment: Just changed my question

Comment: the code you posted does not contain the query.